# Can allow a rspec-mock to receive any calls except specified ones?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test a complicated interaction between 2 Classes:

```
class Class1
  def method1(obj2)
     obj2.call1
     obj2.call2
     .... #calls that I don't care
     obj2.call3(1)
   end
end
```

I want to write a rspec test case similar to this:

```
allow(mock_obj2).to receive_any_message!
expect(mock_obj2).to receive(:call3).with(1)
expect(mock_obj2).not_to receive(:call4)
```

In other words, I'd like my test cases to focus only on :call3 and :call4, while ignoring any other calls.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
mock_obj2 = double(:mock_obj2).as_null_object
expect(mock_obj2).to receive(:call3).with(1)
expect(mock_obj2).not_to receive(:call4)

Class1.new.method1(mock_obj2)
```